# jQuery toggle('slide') toggles visibility state but doesn't have the slide effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have 2 divs `category-block-1` and `category-block-2`. `category-block-2` has `display:none;`. I'm trying to to toggle slide them left to right. Following is what my HTML structure looks like.

```
<div class="top-categories-block">
    <i class="fa fa-caret-left category-left"></i>
    <ul class="top-categories-list">
        <div class="category-block-1">
             ...
        </div>
        <div class="category-block-2">
             ...
        </div>
    </ul>
    <i class="fa fa-caret-right category-right"></i>
</div>
```

My JS code to achieve the above condition is as follows

```
$('.top-categories').on('click', '.category-left', function() {
    $('.category-block-1').toggle('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 500);
    $('.category-block-2').toggle('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 500);
});

$('.top-categories').on('click', '.category-right', function() {
    $('.category-block-1').toggle('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 500);
    $('.category-block-2').toggle('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 500);
});
```

This toggles the visibility state but doesn't have the slide in effect. I have included the jQuery UI js and css files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contents of the 2 `<div>`'s were set to float.

Adding a `<div class="clearfix"></div>` before the closing `</div>` tag for both the `<div>`'s solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try the following. It is working. I have just added a refrence of jQuery UI library and changed 
`$('.top-categories')` to `$('.top-categories-block')`

```
$('.top-categories-block').on('click', '.category-left', function() {
    $('.category-block-1').toggle('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 500);
    $('.category-block-2').toggle('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 500);
});

$('.top-categories-block').on('click', '.category-right', function() {
    $('.category-block-1').toggle('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 500);
    $('.category-block-2').toggle('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 500);
});
```

Here is working code at JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/53dm3yee/1/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly change `.top-categories` to `.top-categories-block` and:

```
$('.category-block-1').show('slide', {direction:'right'}, 500);
$('.category-block-2').show('slide', {direction:'right'}, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks how `$(...).toggle('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 500);` works in different jQuery versions:

[jQuery 1.7.2 + jQuery UI 1.8.18](http://jsfiddle.net/qn5t9o06/)

[jQuery 1.9.1 + jQuery UI 1.9.2](http://jsfiddle.net/qn5t9o06/2/)

[jQuery edge + jQuery UI 1.8.5](http://jsfiddle.net/qn5t9o06/1/) - **not working**